# Facebook AppLink doesen't work with app not installed (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I got an app which creates custom stories on Facebook and clicking on it will open the app. Also I have a website and my app is on the Play Store. With the app installed it works fine, but if the app is not installed it opens a Chrome page then opens Google Play on a blank page. On a Nexus 4 it open the Play Store on Chrome to the exact page. I am so not understaning what is going on...
I followed all the guidelines on my website and configured the app properly on Facebook Developer.
My head on the website is:

```
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="PACKAGENAME" />
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="NAME://main" />
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="APP_NAME" />

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1476418055959535" /> 
    <meta property="og:type" content="NAMESPACE:item" />
```